# is_singular() not working if called via callback function of admin-ajax.php

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, conditional-tags, blog, single

In my `single.php` I've some code like this ...

```
if(is_singular('post')) {
   echo 'Blog';
} else {
   echo 'CPT';
}
```

If I approach `single.php` from blog or CPT index page by using `the_permalink()`, this condition works correctly. It show 'Blog' when I open single blog post and shows 'CPT' when I open single CPT.

Now the issue is if approach `single.php` via some callback function of `admin-ajax.php` it always echos 'CPT' even if I click on single blog post link. My ajax callback function is something like this ...

```
    function ajax_callback() {

        get_template_part( 'single', 'portfolio' );

        die(); // to avoide 0 at the end

    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_callback', 'ajax_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_callback', 'ajax_callback');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AJAX request is a ***new*** request to the server, and it is a request to `admin-ajax.php`. That *is not* a single post page. Any logic that depends on `is_single()` or any other page level template tags like it, won't work. If your AJAX callback needs that sort of information you must pass it to that callback in your AJAX request-- something like:

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
    if( is_single() ) {
      // in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
      wp_localize_script( 
    'ajax-script', 
    'ajax_object',
        array( 'is_single' => true ) 
      );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Your ajax request would then include `ajax_object.is_single` as part of the query parameters as in [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Introduction), which passed `ajax_object.we_value` through as `whatever`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

Your callback would then have access to the data via `$_POST`.

Comment: yes mate, got the point and issue solved. Thnx :)